# Slide-in menu container not sliding

Tags: ios, swift

The MainSideController has function toggleSideMenu. but when I tapped the profile ButtonTapped in ContentViewController. The button show it's tapped in the debug menu but the side menu doesn't slide in.

```
import UIKit

class MainSideViewController: ContentViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var sideMenuContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sideMenuViewLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentViewLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var sideMenuVisible = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sideMenuViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0 - self.sideMenuContainer.frame.size.width
    }

    @objc func toggleSideMenu(fromViewController: UIViewController) {
        if(sideMenuVisible){
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

                self.sideMenuViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0 - self.sideMenuContainer.frame.size.width

                self.contentViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        } else {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

                self.sideMenuViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0

                self.contentViewLeadingConstraint.constant = self.sideMenuContainer.frame.size.width
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }

        sideMenuVisible = !sideMenuVisible
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

class ContentViewController: UIViewController {
    let profileButton = UIButton(type: .custom)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        profileButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "hamburger") , for: .normal)
        profileButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        profileButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // function performed when the button is tapped
        profileButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(profileButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        // Add the profile button as the left bar button of the navigation bar
        let barbutton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: profileButton)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barbutton

        // Set the width and height for the profile button
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            profileButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35.0),
            profileButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35.0)
            ])

          // Make the profile button become circular
          profileButton.layer.cornerRadius = 35.0 / 2
          profileButton.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    @IBAction func profileButtonTapped(_ sender: Any){
        print("Button tapped")

        if let mainVC = self.navigationController?.tabBarController?  .parent as? MainSideViewController {
            mainVC.toggleSideMenu(fromViewController: self)
        }
    }
}
```

I added sideMenuViewLeadingConstraint to the viewDidLoad. 
it still didn't work. I added the toggle function too. it still didn't slide in and out.

I expect the profile button to trigger the toggle function and the side menu to side in like twitter side in and out.

Answer (score 0):

In Place of sideMenuViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0 - self.sideMenuContainer.frame.size.width in the MainSideViewController I used
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(toggleSideMenu), name: NSNotification.Name("ToggleSideMenu"), object: nil)

and placed it in
 @IBAction func profileButtonTapped(_ sender: Any){
        print("Button tapped")

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("ToggleSideMenu"), object: nil)
        }
    }